# I can't find the neovim executable after installing into home directory

Tags: pip, neovim

This command seems to run successfully on macOS High Sierra.

```
pip2 install --user neovim
```

But I can't find the executable... where should it be? It's not in ./Library/Python/2.7/bin (which does not exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why, but I tried installing both pip's neovim and brew's neovim and I now have a single executable that has python supported (based on [this comment](https://github.com/ensime/ensime-vim/issues/320#issuecomment-235301260)).

Comment: Nvim is a C program. The python package is a python library for working with the Nvim RPC API. Two different things. See also `:help provider-python`.

Comment: FWIW the neovim python module was recently renamed to "pynvim" in an effort to avoid this confusion. https://github.com/neovim/pynvim/pull/305